# Pandas tshift slow in groups

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas `tshift` is pretty awesome. It's quite quick!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(1970,1,1),pd.datetime(1970,2,1)))
df['data']=.5
%timeit df.sum()
#10000 loops, best of 3: 162 µs per loop 
%timeit df.tshift(-1)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop #x2 slower
```

But when I do `tshift` after a `groupby` it slows down a lot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(1970,1,1),pd.datetime(1970,2,1)))
df['data']=.5
df['A'] = randint(0,2,len(df.index))
%timeit df.groupby('A').sum()
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.72 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('A').tshift(-1)
#10 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop #x6 slower!
```

Why is `tshift` so much slower when doing grouping? Is there a way to be faster?

Update:

My actual use case is closer to the code below. I see that the size of the slow down multiplier depends on the number of group.

```
n_A = 50
n_B = 5
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([arange(n_A),
                                     arange(n_B),
                                     pd.date_range(pd.datetime(1975,1,1),
                                                   pd.datetime(2010,1,1),
                                                   freq='5AS')],
                                   names=['A', 'B', 'Year'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['data']=.5

%timeit df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).sum()
#100 loops, best of 3: 4.34 ms per loop
%timeit df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).tshift(-1, freq='5AS')
#10 loops, best of 3: 198 ms per loop # X44 slowdown.
```

Whereas if we increase the number of A and B groups:

```
n_A = 500
n_B = 50
...
%timeit df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).sum()
#10 loops, best of 3: 35.8 ms per loop
%timeit df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).tshift(-1, freq='5AS')
#1 loops, best of 3: 20.3 s per loop # X567 slowdown
```

I'm surprised that the slowdown grows with the number of group! Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tshift` requires a freq argument for this usage (because the freq is potentially and usually not regular once you group), so `df.groupby('A').tshift(-1)` returns an empty frame (it is raising for each group, slowing it as well).

```
In [44]: %timeit df.groupby('A').tshift(-1,'D')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit df.groupby('A').sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

Aside from this, this issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4095) is waiting for a cythonized implementation of shift (and tshift) too. Which would make this on par with sum, which is cythonized. Contributions welcome!

Using your 2nd dataset (bigger groups), you can do this:

```
In [59]: def f(df):
   ....:     x = df.reset_index()
   ....:     x['Year_ts'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(x['Year'])-pd.offsets.YearBegin(5)
   ....:     return x.drop(['Year'],axis=1).rename(columns={'Year_ts' : 'Year'}).set_index(['A','B','Year'])
   ....: 

In [60]: result = df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).tshift(-1,'5AS')

In [61]: %timeit df.reset_index(['A','B']).groupby(['A','B']).tshift(-1,'5AS')
1 loops, best of 3: 10.8 s per loop

In [62]: result2 = f(df)

In [63]: %timeit f(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.51 s per loop

In [64]: result.equals(result2)
Out[64]: True
```

So doing the date-subtraction outside of the groupby makes this about 4x faster. And that (and caching) are prob first steps to making a grouped tshift faster.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! See my updates below. My actual code had the freq indicated; I just erroneously dropped it in the example. It looks like my actual issue is the number of groups? n_A and n_B are actually 2k-500k and 121, respectively.

Comment: Ok, the reason for this being slow, is that an individual operation  ends up doing ``timestamp + offset`` (e.g. to add a particular timestamp and the offset (which is negative here)). This is has very specific semantics to when adding months/years to make things land properly and such. In an of itself this operation is fine. However it is done repeatedly many many times. So this *could* be cached to vastly speed this up. Will create an issue to track this.

Comment: Further, you are really doing a completely different type of operation that ``.sum()``, which is a reduction. You are doing essentially a transformation here, that is being repeated.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That sounds like if I ditched the datetimes and just used digits there might be an improvement. At the moment all I'm keeping track of is years. I just tried using floats for years and doing `.transform(lambda x: x-5)`, but that also has this increasing slowdown. Though admittedly less: x13 and x132 for my two examples above. Is there any even better way?

Comment: Sidenote: In the real use case some of the dates are absent. This is why I liked tshift; If the index goes 1975, 1980, 2005 I would end up with 1970, 1975, 2000. For the moment using digits and just calculating x-5 is fine for this purpose, but if I ever switched to proper dates with months/days this would be a bigger issue.

Comment: Oh, and TimeGrouper. I also use that upstream in the pipeline. But maybe I could switch to digits for this step.

Comment: you realize transform with a constant is the same as subtracting 5 from the column (equivalent to my 2nd example) - obviously any group operation is a function of the number of groups - calculation functions are mostly cythonized

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a few minutes after I said that. Which made me wonder "Why was I using datetimes and tshift anyway?". TimeGrouper was the reason why. But I've now modified my code to be less stupid. It's much faster! >_>

Comment: "obviously any group operation is a function of the number of groups - calculation functions are mostly cythonized" But it's not obvious to me that the difference between runtimes of functions X and Y, applied to each group individually, would grow with the number of groups.